# Bootstrap Carousel does not restart

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and having trouble with my `carousel`.
I have 12 items. I managed to start my `Carousel` by using this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 1000,
    cycle: true
  });
  $('[data-slide-to=0]').trigger('click');
});
```

The problem is, the first loop completes successfully, automatically, but when it comes to an end, the big image disappears but nothing happens to the indicators. The Indicators continue to loop from the beginning to the end without the big image.

**Img 1:** *Normal slider, sliding till the end:*
[image]

**Img 2:** *Slider disappears and it's indicators remain and restart from begining as normal.*

[image]

When I open `firebug` and add "active" to the first image, it becomes normal.

How can I set the `Carousel`, so the first item is active when the first indicator is selected?

Here I created a sample [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sulhadin/66o0g8a0/)

Comment: Maybe it's this: `$('[data-slide-to=0').trigger('click');`, you forgot to close the bracket. Although I think this is just a typo.

Comment: it is my bad  and I fixed it. but nothing changed.

Comment: do you have a working https://jsfiddle.net/ to show us?

Comment: here I created one: https://jsfiddle.net/sulhadin/66o0g8a0/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such option as 'cycle' in Bootstrap v3, as it loops by default. Therefore the code should look like:

```
 $(function(){
     $('.carousel').carousel({ interval: 1000 });
 });
```

Also you should get rid of the `item` class in the indicators, because it indicates the slide to animate.

https://jsfiddle.net/66o0g8a0/1/

Comment: I have created a sample JSFiddle I will appriciate that if you check it.